# Solve Differential Equation Numerically

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I investigated my system and encountered differential equation such as

$y''(x) = e^{y(x)}-e^{-2y(x)}-e^{y(x)-y(x+d)}$,

where $d$ is a constant. The boundary condition is

$y'(0) = 30$

$y'(\infty)=0$.

I want to implement this in mathematica using `NDSolve`. Can anyone guide me as I am new to Mathematica?

Comment: To use `NDSolve` you must fix a numerical value of d. After that it is straightforward. Have a look at the Help/DocumentationCenter/NDSolve

Comment: A few other potential issues:  (1) this is a [delay-differential equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html), which means that you need to specify an initial history function, not just an initial condition. Since you have a term of the form $y(x+d)$, this actually corresponds to a "negative delay" (assuming $d > 0$), so you'll have to provide the value of the function $y$ for some interval of time in the future.  ...

Comment: ...  (2) Like most (all?) programming languages, Mathematica cannot numerically solve differential equations on an infinite domain.  You will have to use a numerical value for "infinity" to get it to yield a solution.  Note that both of these issues will arise no matter what programming language you use to try to get a solution.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you, Michael. First, $\psi$ is $y$. In python, from the initial guess of function y and y', we numerically solve the differential equation... Do you mean mathematica can't do like python? Third, I will set infinity as sufficiently large value.

Comment: What library do you use to solve delay-differential equations in Python?  There may be some implicit default assumptions that are implicit in the Python function you're invoking.  But on a mathematical level, independent of the programming language you use, a delay-differential equation problem is not well-posed unless you specify an initial history over a period at least as long as the delay period.

Comment: *from the initial guess of function y and y'* You specify y’ at 0 so there is nothing to guess about that.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I use solve_bvp in scipy library.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with `solve_bvp` but I don't think that it can solve delay-differential equations like this one.  My understanding is that `solve_bvp` requires you to put your equation in the form $y'(x) = f(x, y(x), p)$, where $y$ is a vector of field quantities.  Your equation includes a $y(x + d)$ term, which means that you won't be able to write it in the form that `solve_bvp` needs.  My point is that the $y(x+d)$ term in your equation fundamentally changes how you need to look at the problem;  see my first link in the comments above.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If I use solve_bvp, is it okay to implement y(x+d) - y(x) = y'(x) d ?

Comment: Only if $y'$ is a constant, which is inconsistent with your boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider the case **d = 0**:

```
eq0 = y''[x] - Exp[y[x]] + Exp[-2 y[x]] + 1;
```

with `y'[0] == 30` and `y'[x] == 0` asymptotically for large `x`.  It is useful to know `y[x]` asymptotically as well.

```
ry = Solve[0 == eq0 /. y''[x] -> 0, y[x], Reals] // Flatten
(* {y[x] -> Log[Root[-1 - #1^2 + #1^3 & , 1, 0]]} *)
```

with the approximate value, `0.382245`.  Conveniently, `eq0` has a first integral.

```
iq0 = Integrate[eq0 y'[x], x]
(* (1/2) E^(-2 y[x]) - E^y[x] + y[x] + 1/2 y'[x]^2 *)
```

from which `{y[0], y'[0]}` can be determined from the corresponding asymptotic values.

```
(iq0 /. y'[x] -> 0 /. ry) == (iq0 /. x -> 0 /. y'[0] -> 30);
(r0 = Solve[%, y[0], Reals] // Flatten // First
(* y[0] -> Root[{Root[-1 - #1^2 + #1^3 & , 1, 0]^2 + ... *)
```

with the approximate value `-3.39884`.  `eq0` now can be evaluated as an initial value problem.

```
NDSolveValue[{eq0 == 0, y'[0] == 30, Equal @@ r0}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 46];
p0 = Plot[%, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

A large `WorkingPrecision` is needed, because the solution is a separatrix.

Now, turn to the general case, **d > 0**:

```
eq2 = y''[x] - Exp[y[x]] + Exp[-2 y[x]] + Exp[y[x] - y[x + d]];
```

This delay differential equation must be integrated from large `x` toward `0`, if `NDSolve` is to be used.  But, to do so requires a first-order expression for `y[x + d]` beyond the domain of integration.  We already have the zero-order expression, `ry`.  Insert this into `eq2` as follows.

```
eq3 = FullSimplify[eq2 /. y -> Function[x, z[x] + Log[Root[-1 - #^2 + #^3&, 1, 0]]]]
(* E^(z[x] - z[d + x]) + E^z[x] Root[1 + #^2 + #^3&, 1, 0] + 
   E^(-2 z[x]) Root[-1 + # + 2 #^2 + #^3& , 1, 0] + z''[x] *)
```

Next, linearize the exponentials and assume that `z[x]` decreases exponentially for large `x`, which proves to be true.  Thus, `z[d + x] -> z[x] Exp[k d]`, and

```
FullSimplify[%/z[x] /. {(z''[x] -> k^2 z[x], 
    Exp[a_] -> 1 + a} /. z[d + x] -> z[x] Exp[k d]]
(* -E^(d k) + k^2 + Root[27 + 9 # - 6 #^2 + #^3&, 1, 0] *)

f[d_] := FindRoot[-E^(d k) + k^2 + 
    Root[27 + 9 # - 6 #^2 + #^3&, 1, 0], {k, -1.55}][[1, 2]]
Plot[f[dd], {dd, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {d, k}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

`k` is, evidently, a relatively weak function of `d`.  The integration of `eq3` now can be performed via shooting .  (The following two blocks of code are used instead of the `NDSolve` `Shooting` option to provide greater flexibility.)  As an example, choose `d -> 2`.  (Choosing `d -> 0` would, of course, recover the first curve, above.)

```
sp3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{0 == eq3 /. d -> 2, 
    z[x /; x >= 10] == zm Exp[Rationalize[f[2], 0] (x - 10)], 
    z'[10] == Rationalize[f[2], 0] z[10]}, {z[x], z'[0]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
    zm, WorkingPrecision -> 46, MaxSteps -> 10^6];

Off[ParametricNDSolveValue::ihist]
FindRoot[Last[sp3[zmm]] == 30, {zmm, -83 10^-7, -82 10^-7}, 
    Evaluated -> False, WorkingPrecision -> 46];
First[sp3[zmm] /. %];
Plot[% + ry[[1, 2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

which looks a lot like the first plot, above.  The largest difference occurs where the curvature is greatest.

```
Show[p0, p2, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-1, .4}}]
```

[image]

Note that the `FindRoot` limits were obtained by trial and error, e.g.,

```
sp3[-80 10^-7] // Last
(* 17.32903540764105929046555619940967323250985139 *)
```

seeking a value near `30`.